# Lagrangian derivative quotient rule?

Tags: derivatives

How do I find the Lagrangian derivative of:

$$\frac{D}{Dt} \left(\frac{x}{y^{a}}\right) = 0$$

where a is a constant?

Comment: Do you mean the Lagrangian derivative of $xy^a$ or taking the derivative of that equation on both sides, which would mean another derivative to the LHS?

Comment: Just fixed it, it's $xy^{-a}$

Comment: Just the derivative of the LHS

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{D}{Dt} \frac{x}{y^a} 
&=
\left( 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + v \cdot \nabla
\right)
\frac{x}{y^a}
\\
&= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{x}{y^a}
 + v \cdot \nabla \frac{x}{y^a}
\\
&= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{x}{y^a}
 + v \cdot (1/y^a, -a x/y^{a+1})
\end{align}
To me that seems as far as one can get here.